# Открыть приложение при переходе по ссылке

Tags: java, android

В приложении если пользователь забыл пароль, он вызывает соответствующий пункт меню, после этого на почту пользователя приходит письмо с ссылкой на восстановление. При переходе по этой ссылке должно открываться приложение с открытой активити для ввода нового пароля. Как можно реализовать чтобы приложение открывалось по ссылке?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вам нужно:

1. Создать активити с фильтром интентов, с определёнными параметрами. Например так:

   ```
   <activity
       android:name="ru.test.MainActivity"
       >
       <intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
           <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>

           <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
           <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>

           <data
               android:host="test.ru"
               android:scheme="myapp"/>
       </intent-filter>
   </activity>
   ```
2. Создать ссылку вида `%СХЕМА%://%ХОСТ%`, т.е. если из примера выше, то `myapp://test.ru`

Теперь, если вставить ссылку `myapp://test.ru` в письмо/на сайт и на девайсе есть приложение ваше, то оно откроется на указанной активити. Также можно и какие-то данные передать в параметрах вашего `url` и их в приложении получить. Например `ID` юзера, его мыло etc.

---

Это будет работать только для андроида. Если вы хотите аналогичное поведение и для `iOS` например, то можно взять `Firebase depp linking` - он позволяет создавать одну ссылку, которая будет работать по разному на андроиде, иОСе или в браузере на компе.

Comment: Сделала все, как вы описали, приложение не открывается, есть какие-нибудь способы это отладить?

Comment: @Arina, нужны детали. Кликали ссылку в браузере или в к-л проге, коя принудительно все ссылки в своём браузере открывает? Если последнее - надо в настройках этого приложения это отключить. Также приложение должно быть хотя бы раз запущено после установки/Force Stop, чтобы активити зарегистрировалась в системе на реагирование на интенты.

Comment: @Arina, также лучше сначала проверить, а потом ответ "верным" отмечать)