# Deeplink как открыть приложение напрямую

Tags: java, android

Основное, что мне нужно сделать это открыть приложение напрямую без pop-up который предлагает открыть приложение всеми доступными способами.

Согласно документации в манифесте диплинк можно обьявить 2-мя способами

> The following XML snippet shows how you might specify an intent filter in your manifest for deep linking. The URIs “example://gizmos” and “http://www.example.com/gizmos” both resolve to this activity.

И в манифесте это вот так:

```
<activity
android:name="com.example.android.GizmosActivity"
android:label="@string/title_gizmos" >
<intent-filter android:label="@string/filter_view_http_gizmos">
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
    <!-- Accepts URIs that begin with "http://www.example.com/gizmos” -->
    <data android:scheme="http"
          android:host="www.example.com"
          android:pathPrefix="/gizmos" />
    <!-- note that the leading "/" is required for pathPrefix-->
</intent-filter>
<intent-filter android:label="@string/filter_view_example_gizmos">
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
    <!-- Accepts URIs that begin with "example://gizmos” -->
    <data android:scheme="example"
          android:host="gizmos" />
</intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Если я правильно понимаю то я не могу просто открыть вот такую ссылку: `example://gizmos`
это ссылка, которую я могу открыть из внешней аппликации при использовании интента.

А вот эта ссылка: `http://www.example.com/gizmos`
как раз для того, чтобы ее отправлять по мейлу(допустим) и открывать ее при нажатии.

Верно ли я понимаю? Потому что я уже разными способами попробовал отправить себе ссылку такого вида: `example://gizmos`, но она никак не распознается.

Или как правильно это сделать?

Мне нужно, чтоб человек нажал ссылку и приложение сразу открылось.

Comment: Вы имеете в виду, что сторонние приложения не делают `example://gizmos` кликабельной и именно по этому вы не можете по ней перейти? А если сделать её кликабельной вручную (например в письме указать что это ссылка) - то работает?

Comment: @ЮрийСПб я подкоректировал вопрос. И да, я пробовал открыть ворд присвоить гиперссылку , скопировать и отправить по почте, но все равно когда открываю с телефона почту и нажимаю на эту ссылку, то ничего не происходит

Comment: Странно... Должно работать)

Comment: Попробуйте всё в один фильтр положить, не разнося по 2-м как сейчас

Comment: @ЮрийСПб хмм, не работает... Я ничего не упустил? Вот что я сделал, добавил фильтр в манифест, потом создал ссылку `example://gizmos` и присвоил гиперссыку с тем же адресом `example://gizmos` отправил эту ссылку по майлу и теперь нужно открыть почту через телефон и кликнуть по ссылке и все должно работать, верно?

Comment: да, должно именно так работать.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб вы делали такую имплементацию? Или чисто теоретически это должно получиться? Я просто уже 2 раза протестил на разных апп. Может дело в андроид P

Comment: Сам лично не делал, но всегда считал что должно работать) Может да, дело в версии ОС

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Судя по всему проблема в отсутствии домена в хосте. Т.е. вот так должно [работать](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/725131/17609):

```
android:host="gizmos.ru"
```

Проверял на 2 девайсах - ссылка в `html` в `Chrome` при нажатии открывает приложение. Вот html для теста:

```
<html>

    <header><title>Test of deep link</title></header>

    <body>

        <a href="example://gizmos.ru">example://gizmos.ru</a>

    </body>

</html>
```

На эмуляторах проверить не удалось - они или хрома у меня не содержат или умирают при попытке протестировать такое. Стоящее на одном из эмуляторов приложение `HtmlViewer` открывал ссылку в себе, не пытаясь проверить есть ли кто для её запуска.

Comment: Да, действительно как `html` если открывать то все работает, но теперь интересно как это запихнуть в mail. Потому, что как я говорил, если присваивать гиперссылку при отправке письма то все равно когда я открываю его и пробую нажать то ничего не происходит. Вообще идея такая же как и описано в том вопросе который вы прикрепили в ссыке. То есть юзер меняет пароль , получает письмо на почту и при переходе по ссылке должно открыться приложение

Comment: @AlekseyTimoshchenko, насколько я понял ситуацию с письмами там просто не кликабельны ссылки с неизвестными схемами. Т.е. если схема не `http(s)` то ссылка не кликабельна. Решить это, по идее, можно, если само письмо будет в html свёрстано. Но это тоже будет половинчатое решение, т.к. не учитывает `iOS`. Надо делать так: давать ссылку на свой сервак, который будет при переходе редирект делать на нужную ссылку в зависимости от вызывающего девайса. Так сделано, например в `Firebase Deep Links`